# Disable freecall from autorun in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, boot

I installed voip program called Freecall in my Windows 7 Professional laptop. Now it shows as a Startup item in "System Configuration" console. I tried to uncheck it in the Startup item and restart, but it keeps on adding itself to HKCU\Software|Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run. How to remove these kinds of programs from the startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) for managing these kinds of programs. However, if you don't wish to download another program you could try msconfig:

1. Open the start menu and select run
2. type msconfig
3. when the dialogue opens select the Startup tap
4. Uncheck the box for freecall

If that doesn't work, take a look at Autoruns.

Comment: used both autoruns and msconfig..i don't seem to find a way to delete the HKCU\Software|Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run entry in the msconfig console

Comment: Open Freecell, select Tools/Options/Advanced and uncheck the box for 'Start freecall when I start Windows'

Comment: ok.it worked..i think its the same for Yahoo messenger..these programs keep on adding to startup even after I manually deleted the entry from the registry. I want to debug and find out if after starting the executable, the program writes to the registry. How can I do that?

Comment: To see if an application makes calls to the registry you'd need to use something like Process Monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx and create a filter for your specific query